# Insert changed xml text with indentation in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I am reading the content of a div which contains a xml-string in xml formatting and indentations into a xml object. Now I need to remove some tags in the xml file and put the changed object into the div.

The removing part is working and the changed object is also visible to the user via `$("div").val(xml.text());` but I don't want to destroy the indentation of the xml string.

I saw that with `$("div").val(xml.html());` the original string is displayed. Without the changes.

How can I remove these xml-tags and display the changes to the user but with the indentation also still visible?

EDIT: Her is my example code:

```
 function removeSensibleParts() {
 xml = $($.parseXML($("#NewXMLContent").val()));

 auftragnr = xml.find("auftragnr");
 auftragnr_prev = auftragnr.prev();

 mitarbnr = xml.find("mitarbnr");
 mitarbnr_prev = mitarbnr.prev();

 inv_seriennr = xml.find("inv_seriennr");
 inv_seriennr_prev = inv_seriennr.prev();

 einsatzdatum = xml.find("einsatzdatum");
 einsatzdatum_prev = einsatzdatum.prev();

 auftragnr.remove();
 mitarbnr.remove();
 inv_seriennr.remove();
 einsatzdatum.remove();

 $("#NewXMLContent").val(xml.text());

 // XMLDefinition = $("#NewXMLContent").val().split("?>")[0] + "?>";
 // $("#NewXMLContent").val($("#NewXMLContent").val().replace(XMLDefinition, "").substring(1));
 }
```